# data/statistic tracking for users in android application

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I have a listview populated by a text file hosted on my website that is parsed and made into seperate list items. Each list item sends the user to a new activity to view more information on that item. My question is - how do I go about tracking the following data about my application..

- ## of views of the whole listview
- ## of unique views of the listview
- ## of times each list item is clicked
- ## of unique clicks of each list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is more about how do you get the data back you may want to look into a service like http://www.flurry.com/. They provide tools for collecting and reporting usage data back to their service.

Comment: That seems interesting. Without going into too much detail, what's their business model? It seems that they provide the analytics module for free - what's in it for them? Or are they just nice people?